# Stacking HPE 2920

Tags: hp, hp-procurve, stacking

I have some 2920 that are running in our DC which for some reason was never stacked, and now I'd like to fix that after the fact. I have all the gear, and I've done stack installations on brand new switches before, but what I can't find any info on is what will happen with the port configurations on the switches when you stack them? Will the be kept or do I have to redo them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the command to enable stacking ("stacking enable") also wipes the config.  This includes all the global config as well as the port configuration.